# How to delete an object in the lightning controller

Tags: apex, data, lightning

So I have managed to get the object I want to delete through my method, however I am not sure how I would go about deleting it - I have spent the last thirty minutes going through the documentation and looking on here but just can't seem how to do it.
So far I have this in my controller:

```
destroy : function(component, evt, helper) {
  var expense = component.get("v.expense");
}
```

I was wondering how I would destroy this instance.

PS

I understand that I need more experience but I like to jump into things and find things out for myself plus it makes me research and read about a variety of things finding out the issue.

Comment: do you want to delete expense or the component itself. If the expense then [pass  them in controller and perform DML.

Comment: ah thank you I've seen my problem now I was trying to delete the expense

Comment: Would you have any tips on how to do that by any chance? :)

Answer (score 1):

first pass this list in controller

```
destroy : function(component) {
    var action = component.get("c.dltexpense");

    action.setParams({
        expenseList  : component.get("v.expense");
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        if (a.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
            console.log(a.getReturnValue());
        } else if (a.getState() === "ERROR") {
            $A.log("Errors", a.getError());
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Now in controller delete this records

```
 @AuraEnabled
    public static boolean dltexpense(List<expense__c> expenseList ) {
       delete expenseList;
       return true;
    }
```

use this. It will solve your problem.

Comment: I've tried this and keep running into this issue: **Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined**

Comment: which line causing this error

Comment: I believe it is this code here **action.setParams({
        expenseList  : component.get("v.expense")
    });**

Comment: did you add controller in component. Also check if you are getting record in `component.get("v.expense")`

Comment: Yeah I have a component already and I am getting the record as its being used in the same controller in a different method

Comment: are you using this in component or in helper. pass all reference as parameter correctly.

Comment: I am using the components controller, and referenced everything correctly.